Flutter notification is not showing on real device but works just fine on emulator
SO i was trying to send notification to the user, and wrote this code, basically its more like a reminder app, user will create a reminder and my app will give them a notification on exact time.
every function works just fine but notification is not showing on real devices, on emulator it shows notification btw.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'dart:io'; // Import for platform checking

class GcalcScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GcalcScreenState createState() => _GcalcScreenState();
}

class _GcalcScreenState extends State<GcalcScreen> {
  bool isDarkMode = false;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> reminders = [];
  int nextReminderId = 1; // Increment for each reminder
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  TimeOfDay selectedTime = TimeOfDay.now();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadThemePreference();
    _loadReminders();
    _initializeNotifications();
    _requestNotificationPermissions(); // Request notification permissions
  }

  // Load the theme preference from SharedPreferences
  void _loadThemePreference() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      isDarkMode = prefs.getBool('isDarkMode') ?? false;
    });
  }

  // Initialize Awesome Notifications
  void _initializeNotifications() {
    AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      'resource://drawable/res_app_icon',
      [
        NotificationChannel(
          channelKey: 'gcalc_channel',
          channelName: 'Graphics Calculator Notifications',
          channelDescription: 'Notification channel for graphics calculator',
          defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
          ledColor: Colors.white,
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  // Request notification permissions
  void _requestNotificationPermissions() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final status = await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed();
      if (!status) {
        AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
      }
    }
  }

  // Load reminders from SharedPreferences
  void _loadReminders() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? remindersString = prefs.getString('reminders');
    if (remindersString != null) {
      List<dynamic> jsonList = json.decode(remindersString);
      reminders = jsonList.map((item) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(item)).toList();
      nextReminderId = reminders.isNotEmpty ? reminders.last['id'] + 1 : 1; // Update next reminder ID
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  // Save reminders to SharedPreferences
  void _saveReminders() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('reminders', json.encode(reminders));
  }

  // Method to send a reminder notification
  void _sendReminder(String message, DateTime dateTime, bool isActive, int id) {
    if (isActive) {
      AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
          channelKey: 'gcalc_channel',
          id: id,
          title: 'Reminder!',
          body: message,
        ),
        schedule: NotificationCalendar(
          year: dateTime.year,
          month: dateTime.month,
          day: dateTime.day,
          hour: dateTime.hour,
          minute: dateTime.minute,
          second: 0,
          millisecond: 0,
          preciseAlarm: true,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  // Show dialog for setting a reminder
  void _setReminder() {
    String reminderMessage = '';

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Set Reminder"),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        reminderMessage = value;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter reminder message",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Text("Select Time:"),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    TimeOfDay? pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialTime: selectedTime,
                    );

                    if (pickedTime != null) {
                      selectedTime = pickedTime;
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text("Pick Time"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (reminderMessage.isNotEmpty) {
                  DateTime reminderDateTime = DateTime(
                    selectedDate.year,
                    selectedDate.month,
                    selectedDate.day,
                    selectedTime.hour,
                    selectedTime.minute,
                  );
                  _sendReminder(reminderMessage, reminderDateTime, true, nextReminderId);
                  reminders.add({
                    'id': nextReminderId,
                    'message': reminderMessage,
                    'dateTime': reminderDateTime.toIso8601String(),
                    'isActive': true,
                  });
                  nextReminderId++;
                  _saveReminders();

                  // Call setState to refresh the UI
                  setState(() {});

                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }
              },
              child: Text("Set"),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text("Cancel"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // Method to cancel a reminder
  void _cancelReminder(int id) {
    AwesomeNotifications().cancel(id);
    reminders.removeWhere((reminder) => reminder['id'] == id);
    _saveReminders();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Reminders"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
              isDarkMode
                  ? 'Asset/images/bg_dark.png' // Dark mode background
                  : 'Asset/images/bg_light.png', // Light mode background
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // Calendar Widget
            TableCalendar(
              focusedDay: selectedDate,
              firstDay: DateTime.utc(2020, 1, 1),
              lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 12, 31),
              selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(selectedDate, day),
              onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedDate = selectedDay;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            // Reminders Card
            Expanded(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 8, // Increased elevation for the card
                child: reminders.isNotEmpty
                    ? ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: reminders.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final reminder = reminders[index];
                    DateTime reminderDateTime = DateTime.parse(reminder['dateTime']);
                    String formattedTime = "Time: ${reminderDateTime.hour}:${reminderDateTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
                    String formattedDate = "Date: ${reminderDateTime.day}/${reminderDateTime.month}/${reminderDateTime.year}";

                    return Dismissible(
                      key: Key(reminder['id'].toString()),
                      background: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.delete,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onDismissed: (direction) {
                        _cancelReminder(reminder['id']);
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(content: Text("Reminder deleted")),
                        );
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(reminder['message']),
                        subtitle: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(formattedTime),
                            Text(formattedDate),
                          ],
                        ),
                        trailing: Switch(
                          value: reminder['isActive'],
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              reminder['isActive'] = value;
                              if (value) {
                                _sendReminder(
                                  reminder['message'],
                                  reminderDateTime,
                                  true,
                                  reminder['id'],
                                );
                              } else {
                                AwesomeNotifications().cancel(reminder['id']);
                              }
                              _saveReminders();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
                    : Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "No reminders set.",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 24,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _setReminder, // Show dialog to set reminder
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}


So, i thought it was a problem in my code, so i tried out example code of awesome notification package and got the same result, notifications are showing on emulator but nothing is coming up on real devices

did you check your phones settings (e.g. notification for the app enabled, dnd mode, ...)

yeah i did, eventually it asks for permission and even after allowing it nothing happens

Connect the device to your system and log it to see what it logs
flutter logs

In Android 13, which is API 33 and later, have you given permission separately in AndroidManifest.xml?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>


umm no, but it doesn't even work on lower api like 22/23.
only works on emulator, i will try it out and let you know the result

OK, I'm waiting

i got no luck, still the same as before. is there any friendly way to do this notification stuffs?
